# Rails 3.1 Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a routing error that I simply cannot figure out! Its doing my head in, if anyone can suggest a solution that would be hugely appreciated.

I get the error:
ROUTING ERROR
No route matches {:action=>"create_from_template", :controller=>"projects"}

from the following button:

```
<p><%= link_to "Create from template", create_from_template_project_path %></p>
```

In routes.rb I have:

```
  resources :projects do
    member do
      get 'create_from_template'
    end
  end
```

In class ProjectsController I have:

```
  def create_from_template
    #@project = Project.find(params[:template_id])
    #@project.clone
    redirect_to projects_path
  end
```

It also shows up when I do "rake routes"

```
create_from_template_project GET    /projects/:id/create_from_template(.:format) {:action=>"create_from_template", :controller=>"projects"}
```

Anyone have any idea why it isnt working?

EDIT: Actually maybe I have misunderstood the "member" nested resource routing rules. I wasnt passing in a project. I have changed the button from

to

```
   <p><%= link_to "Create from template", create_from_template_project_path(template_project) %></p>
```

and now it works. Thanks everyone that helped.

Comment: Do you see the route in "rake routes" list?

Comment: rake routes |grep create_from_template

Comment: yes i do, 
create_from_template_project GET    /projects/:id/create_from_template(.:format) {:action=>"create_from_template", :controller=>"projects"}

Comment: try sending the project in the path alongside link_to

Comment: i guess that worked, so i'll add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you dont need to pass project for creating template action,change button as:
`

```
 <%= link_to "Create from template", create_from_template_projects_path %>
```

In routes, instead of

```
 member do
```

you should use

```
 collection do
```

If you use `member do` in routes.rb then you should pass project in the link_to as Prasvin has mentioned

Answer (score 4):

try sending the project in the path alongside link_to